# using foreign key value directly in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

is it possible to use the value of the foreign key directly with an `INSERT INTO` statement? I am using `Postgresql` and the tables are consttructed as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE public.sensors
(
    name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('sensors_id_seq'::regclass),
    CONSTRAINT sensors_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)

)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.sensors
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Now I also have another table, defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE public.testmap
(
    sensor_id integer NOT NULL,
    "timestamp" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    value "char" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ragmap_sensor_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (sensor_id)
        REFERENCES public.sensors (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.ragmap
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Now, I try to insert a record directly into the `testmap` table as:

```
INSERT INTO testmap (sensor_id, timestamp, value) VALUES (1, NOW(), 'r')
```

I have a record inserted into the `sensors` table where the id is 1. However, when I try the `INSERT INTO` operation, I get:

```
DETAIL:  Key (sensor_id)=(1) is not present in table "sensors".
```

Is there a way to use the `INSERT INTO` with the foreignh key directly without having to resort to another `Select` for the relevant row selection in the `sensors` table?

Comment: Can you please check that the create table statement you've posted for the sensors table is correct? It has the `id` column defined twice, with different types

Comment: Also suggest giving this page a read, in particular I'd consider using the `text` type for the fields you have defined as char/varchar https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This

Comment: @Michael Good catch. Sorry about that. The table had many other columns and I removed them for brevity and this was a copy/paste bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't even work.  The column `id` is specified more than once for `sensors`.

I don't recommend having a character column as a primary key.  If you do so, you should be explicit about your types:

```
INSERT INTO testmap (sensor_id, timestamp, value)
    VALUES ('1', NOW(), 'r');
```

The problem is that your foreign key reference is a number but the primary key is an integer.

Instead, define the primary key to be a number:

```
CREATE TABLE public.sensors (
    id serial primary key,
    name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('sensors_id_seq'::regclass),
    CONSTRAINT sensors_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I had a small bug with copy/pasting where I forgot to remove a column which would not have added anything to the discussion. Is there also some casting operator from number to integer? I had tried `INTEGER(1)` but that had not worked previously.